# Show pointer value in kernel printouts (instead of <ptr>) on parallels VM that runs OS X 10.12

Tags: c, macos, kernel, virtual-machine, xnu

I'm working on a Kext that runs under 10.12.4 VM (I use parallels) and I'd like to enable pointer printouts (currently all pointers are hidden and appears on `/var/log/system.log` as `<ptr>`)

Prior to 10.12 there was option to directly put away debugging restrictions by setting `nvram csr-active-config=%ff%00%00%00`. However, now it's impossible to set `csr-active-config` directly but through `csrutil disable` from recovery mode. unfortunately, it doesn't disable all SIP features and the pointers remain hidden.

luckily, the following [thread](https://github.com/openzfsonosx/zfs/issues/461#issuecomment-177052785) that offers workaround :

> Alternatively, CSR can be disabled entirely by setting csr-active-config=ff%00%00%00. For a VM this can be achieved by booting to the Recovery partition, running csrutil clear to delete the csr-active-config variable entirely and nvram Xsr-active-config=ff%00%00%00. Then shutdown the VM, and use a hex editor to change X -> c in the nvram file. This will allow the -show_pointers boot-arg to work.

I'm working with Parallels, and I try to find the location of nvram settings. I saw promising file called `NVRAM.dat` but unfortunately
I couldn't trace the string `Xsr-active-config` after I've followed the instructions in the quoted paragraph above.

Perhaps there's another place for the nvram settings ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a *direct* answer to your question, but I have a workaround: the output to the `kprintf()` serial log is *not* pointer-sanitised. So if you enable the kprintf flag in the debug boot-args, activate a virtual serial port which writes to a host file in the VM setup and change your logging from `printf`/`IOLog` to `kprintf`, you can get raw logging to your serial port file.

I find the `kprintf()` logging mechanism more helpful than the kernel syslog in other ways too - it works right up to a panic, it's not rate-limited, and it's less noisy. The downside is it has a noticeable performance impact if you log a lot.

Answer (score 1):

change doprnt_hide_pointers to false in a debugger

Comment: Nice, I wasn't aware of this global... I did wonder how panic shows the pointers properly, while every other method hides it..